# Laravel calculate total balance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my Table:

```
| id  | type   | balance 
| ----|--------| -------
| 1   | credit | 2400
| 2   | credit | 4800
| 3   | debit  | 1200
```

The calculated amount should be 6000. (2400 + 4800 - 1200) = 6000

How can I do this using Eloquent or collection?

Comment: Can you make the balance with negative sign if it's a debit? then you can use sum() method on the model. it will be much easier than other alternatives.

Comment: That would work, but I need to know the total the creditted amount as well. I did this to solve this. 
return Model::all()->reduce(function ($carry, $item) { 
  return $item->type == 'credit' 
     ? $carry + $item->balance : $carry - $item->balance; 
},0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using laravel collection and one SQL query.

```
return Model::all()->reduce(function ($carry, $item) { 
  return $item->type == 'credit' 
     ? $carry + $item->balance : $carry - $item->balance; 
},0);
```

Comment: Why did you un accepted the working answer ? Can you please tell us what was wrong with my answer above ? Not sure why you even posted a question if you are accepting your own answers or unaccepting where you have accepted before.

Comment: Very inefficient solution. Fetching all entries for calculating a balance? This is killing the performance. The sum should be done on the MySQL side as @AlwaysHelping solution is.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by this using Eloquent:

**Credits**

```
$totalCredits = Model::where('type', 'credit')->sum('balance');
```

**Debits**

```
$totalDebits = Model::where('type', 'debit')->sum('balance');
```

**Balances**

```
$Total =  $totalCredits - $totalDebits
```

**If you want SUM only then do this**

```
DB::table("table")->get()->sum("balance")
```

Comment: it is 7200 but it should be 600. Calculation is (2400 + 4800 - 1200) = 6000

Comment: Updated the answer to archive what you want.

Comment: How about this one?

return Model::all()->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
            return $item->type == 'c' 
                ? $carry + $item->balance : $carry - $item->balance;
}, 0);

Comment: I have not and I do not need to. Thanks. Timestamp will be helpfull. Have a good day